# 0x8badf00d in React native iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing a React Native (0.45.0) application and once in a couple of hours my application crashes (or rather gets killed by watchdog) with 0x8badf00d. I understand why watchdog kills the application; the main thread takes longer than 20 seconds to respond to an event. But I have no idea how to debug this in React Native. Everything is in Javascript and in promises so I am assuming that the network execution that I am doing is already asynchronous.

The application seems to be only crashing while it's in the background. However, the crash reports role states Foreground. We are using background fetch and background geolocation which both do a network request. I have measured the time from event trigger to finish and it does not take longer than one second in total.

I read that the most common problem for this error to happen is a network request on the main threat. Could it be that it tries to load the js bundle synchronously and hangs? How can I debug this problem when all my code is in Javascript?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
Incident Identifier: 36E63A5F-7C40-40C0-9914-2C9EAE494C11
Beta Identifier:     3C432B54-1947-470E-A387-6566A494E145
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:              [993]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/70B3363C-32E9-4D26-B6C6-DB51304D46C7/.app/
Identifier:          org.reactjs.native.example.Test3
Version:             20 (1.4)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.reactjs.native.example.Test3 [703]


Date/Time:           2017-07-17 21:31:33.1931 -0400
Launch Time:         2017-07-17 19:18:30.9574 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace <0xF>, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x0000000182a07224 0x182a06000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x0000000182a0709c 0x182a06000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                
0x00000001839d8e90 0x1838fe000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                
0x00000001839d6ae4 0x1838fe000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                
0x0000000183906da4 0x1838fe000 + 36260
5   GraphicsServices              
0x0000000185370074 0x185364000 + 49268
6   UIKit                         
0x0000000189bc1058 0x189b4c000 + 479320
7                     
0x00000001000bfa08 0x1000b8000 + 31240
8   libdyld.dylib                 
0x000000018291559c 0x182911000 + 17820
```

**Update**, symbolized part of the crash log:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182faf224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182faf09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f80e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f7eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183eaeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000185918074 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                           0x000000018a169058 UIApplicationMain + 208
7                       0x0000000100063294 0x10005c000 + 29332
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182ebd59c start + 4
```

Comment: For other people coming here. This problem can be so many things, for us it was that incoming push notifications were triggering a background job that took too long to finish.

Comment: What steps you take to debug the error , I am unable to understand these crash logs . :( anyways

Comment: @prateeakojha, you could start by looking at your background jobs. When you figured out when it triggers, try disabling the background jobs, try disabling the background modes you have available in your app so they won't be execute. See if you are doing anything that takes a long time in one of those jobs.